# execute a for loop in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, socket.io

I have been trying to get the value of a variable after execution of a for loop in node js. But it is showing as undefined. But the same variable is getting the desired value when I call the variable in setTimeout function after 5000ms. I don't want to use setTimeout because it varies from user to user  who uses my application.

The code with which I'm trying is

```
function getQuestions()
 {
  for(x=0;x<sevenQIDs.length;x++)
   {
    var query = connection.query('SELECT QUESTION, OP1, OP2, OP3, OP4, ANS FROM QUESTIONS WHERE QUESTION_ID="'+sevenQIDs[x]+'"', function(err,result,fields){
    if(err){
      throw err;    
    } 
    else{
      var a = result[0];
      var resTime = [], resAns = [];
      resTime.length = 5;
      resAns.length = 5;
      a.resTime = resTime;
      a.resAns = resAns;
      sevenQues.push(a);
     }
   });
 }
}

socket.on('socket1', function(text) 
 {
   getQuestions();
   console.log(sevenQues);
 }
```

Here sevenQues is a global variable and I'm getting undefined in the console. But when I put this
    setTimeout(function()
     {
         console.log(sevenQues);
     },5000);

I'm getting the desired value. Please help me to resolve this issue and I heard of some async.js file which can do the foreach loop to send the desired output. But I'm unable to get this done. Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Comment: classic. it is asynchronous call, you need to use callback to ensure you access sevenQues after last push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function getQuestions(callback)
 {
  for(x=0;x<sevenQIDs.length;x++)
   {
    var query = connection.query('SELECT QUESTION, OP1, OP2, OP3, OP4, ANS FROM QUESTIONS WHERE QUESTION_ID="'+sevenQIDs[x]+'"', function(err,result,fields){
    if(err){
      throw err;    
    } 
    else{
      var a = result[0];
      var resTime = [], resAns = [];
      resTime.length = 5;
      resAns.length = 5;
      a.resTime = resTime;
      a.resAns = resAns;
      sevenQues.push(a);
      if(x == sevenQIDs.length-1) callback();
     }
   });
 }
}

socket.on('socket1', function(text) 
 {
   getQuestions(function(){console.log(sevenQues)});
 }
```

Comment: Thanx, but callback is getting displayed 7 times for each for loop query, i only need the end result which is set of 7 question.

Comment: than place it in if condition and call it on last iteration.

Comment: Thanx,  but in if condition the loop is getting executed all 7 times i.e I'm getting my x value 7 as all time is there any way to control it.